# Cargo build artifact produced by GitHub Action does not execute locally

Tags: ubuntu, rust, continuous-integration, github-actions, rust-cargo

I am trying to build a simple "Hello World" Rust program and create a GitHub release using an artifact of the build process. The toolchain being used is `stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`, which has no problems when running `cargo build` or `cargo run` locally. The release itself, along with the produced binary, can be found [here](https://github.com/ap-1/color_difference/releases/tag/latest). The GitHub Action logs can be found [here](https://github.com/ap-1/color_difference/runs/4748946667?check_suite_focus=true).

The action is able to create the release, but the produced binary does not execute on my system (Ubuntu 21.10 impish). In the following commands, the name of the downloaded binary is `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.

```sh
$ bash x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu: cannot execute binary file
```

```sh
$ ./x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
bash: ./x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu: Permission denied
```

After trying to add permissions using `chmod u+x x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`, the above command produces no output.

```sh
$ file x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=cb612cdcb3dfb4866238c50e96b9799037e427a2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

```sh
$ file /lib/systemd/systemd
/lib/systemd/systemd: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=055a1b9666c7d1677a2942d46ca47e59fe75dae5, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

```sh
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

---

src/main.rs:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

.github/workflows/release.yml:

```yaml
name: Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG: true
  PROJECT_NAME: color_difference

jobs:
  linux:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        rust:
          - stable

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install toolchain
        uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          toolchain: ${{ matrix.rust }}
          override: true
          profile: minimal

      - name: Set up cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: |
            ~/.cargo/bin/
            ~/.cargo/registry/index/
            ~/.cargo/registry/cache/
            ~/.cargo/git/db/
            target/
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-cargo-${{ hashFiles('**/Cargo.lock') }}

      - name: Build sources
        uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: build
          args: --release

      - name: Run UPX
        uses: crazy-max/ghaction-upx@v1
        with:
          version: latest
          files: target/release/${{ env.PROJECT_NAME }}
          args: --brute

      - name: Rename file
        run: cp target/release/${{ env.PROJECT_NAME }} x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

      - name: Release with artifacts
        uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
        with:
          name: Release
          tag: latest
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          commit: ${{ github.sha }}
          artifacts: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: About https://github.com/ap-1/color_difference/releases/tag/latest .......... Execute an executable / the executable  x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu : Do not use bash (that's for "text.sh"), but please do `$ ./x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

Comment: Have you tried `./x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` _after_ the `chmod +x`?

Comment: @Jmb yes, the command then produces no output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Apparently, UPX somehow breaks the Linux executable. However, when I tried to build a Windows executable, UPX still worked fine. In order to fix my GitHub Action workflow, I made the following changes:

```yaml
# old
- name: Run UPX
  uses: crazy-max/ghaction-upx@v1
  with:
    version: latest
    files: target/release/${{ env.PROJECT_NAME }}
    args: --brute
```

```yaml
# new
- name: Strip artifact
  run: strip target/release/${{ env.PROJECT_NAME }}

- name: Run UPX
  run: echo "Not supported on linux platform"
```